How to change from weight paint to automatic weight
I’m really new to Blender.
I was moving on to rigging a model and was supposed to select ‘with automatic weights’, but selected ‘with empty weights’ or Paint Weight, I think?
When I click Ctrl + P on the mesh and armature, it doesn’t come up with the options anymore, and I don’t know how to undo it.

The easiest option would just be to clear the parenting and do it again, though I wonder why you can’t undo.
The second option is to:

Select the armature.
Go into Pose mode.
Select all bones with A.
Go back to Object mode.
Select the mesh object.
Go into Weight Paint mode.
Assign the weights automatically from the 3D Viewport header Weights menu as shown here.

